# Не отправляются данные через Telegram.WebApp.sendData

Tags: javascript, python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть бот, написанный с помощью pyTelegramBotApi.

Я пытаюсь отправить данные с веб-приложения, запущенного через bot menu-кнопку, на телеграмм бота с помощью `window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData('test');`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вчера данные отправлялись, хоть и приходилось после каждой отправки данных перезаходить в чат, чтобы отправить их снова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сегодня же данные не отправляются совсем.

В ниже приведенных ссылках, пишут что sendData работает только если запуск идет через обычную клавиатуру, а не через inline, коей является кнопка Menu. Хотя в примере @DurgerKingBot, все вроде как работает через inline-кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909144/dont-get-a-response-from-from-telegram-web-app-for-bots

https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/24390

Примечание. Проблема именно в вызове через inline-кнопку, через обычную все прекрасно работает

Comment: добавь код что ли..

Comment: window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData('test'); - функция телеграммовского api

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(telebot.InlineKeyboardButton("text", web_app=telebot.types.WebAppInfo("ссылка")))
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=markup)`

Comment: @highpassion проблема не в том, что я не знаю как это написать, а в том что при запуске приложения через inline-клавиаутуру веб-приложение отказывается отправлять данные обратно боту по запросу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На официальном сайте Телеграм написано что
sendData() можно отправить только через Keyboard button

> This method is only available for Web Apps launched via a Keyboard button.

Как вариант с решением этой проблемы, можно создать свой сервер который будет ловить запросы с Web App и делать нужное Вам поведение. Этим сервером одновременно может и быть процесс который отвечает за бота.

То есть, пользователь заходит на Order Food -> 
Например нажимает на кнопку -> 
Web App отправляет запрос на ваш бек -> 
Бек отправляет инфу на сервер с ботом (или бек и есть ваш сервер с ботом) -> 
Вы выполняете нужные действия (отправляете например текст пользователю) -> 
Возвращаете Response в Web App -> 
И выполняете `window.Telegram.WebApp.close()`

В итоге поведение будет аналогичное тому что Вам нужно

Когда отправляете запрос с WebApp на Ваш сервер для идентификации юзера можно получить например вот так
`window.Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe.user`

Comment: Да спасибо, я о подобном методе тоже думал, но проблема в том что iniDataUnsafe пустая если запускать через встроенную кнопку *This object contains data that is transferred to the Web App when it is opened. It is empty if the Web App was launched from a keyboard button.*
[Документация](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#webappinitdata)

Comment: А можешь подробнее рассказать по идентификации юзера через window.Telegram.WebApp.initData эта штука содержит хеш ключ зашифрованный, его надо будет сравнить каким-то образом на бэке с помощью hmac256, используя токен бота и секретную соль. Но не до конца понятно, как эта штука будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Если в initDataUnsafe ничего нет, то данные можно передавать через url-параметры GET запроса к webapp.

```
https://example.com/webapp?hello=<user_id>
```